# jScrollPane vanishes after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jscrollpane

I'm having an issue where jScrollPane shows up when I load data into a container through an Ajax call, but vanishes when I attempt to make a second call (data is loaded into the container by clicking on different parts of a map). I tried reinitializing jScrollPane but had no luck. Any ideas on what the problem may be? Below are is the source code and you'll see a section commented out. Both the commented out section and the api reference to jScrollPane seem to function in the same manner, but neither are able to get the scroll bar to reinitialize.

```
function getMapData(){
    joinedStatesSelected = mapSelectedArrayForQuery.join();
    var url = 'loc='+joinedStatesSelected+'';
        alert(url);
    ajaxMapRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../availabilities/maps?"+url,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(x){
            $('#temporaryMapDirection').remove();
            $('.map-right-container').html(x);

            /*
            $('.map-right-container').jScrollPane({
                autoReinitialise:true,
                autoReinitialiseDelay:100,
                maintainPosition: false,
                hideFocus: true
                });
            */

            var mapContent = $('.map-right-container').jScrollPane();
            var api = mapContent.data('jsp');

            api.reinitialise();


            mapPropertyCount();

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you update the `html` of the element which contains the `jScrollPane`.
So you need to update only the content of the element containing the scrollpane and then call `reinitialise`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3yDX9/

In your case you should write something like,

`$('.map-right-container div.content').html(x);`

If however it is really required to set the html, as it is done in the example then it is required to `destroy` the `jScrollPane` before setting the html content and then create it again.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jx5eJ/

In your case it would be something like,

```
....

var pane = $('.map-right-container')
    var api = pane.data('jsp');
    api.destroy();

$('.map-right-container').html(x);

/*
$('.map-right-container').jScrollPane({
  autoReinitialise:true,
  autoReinitialiseDelay:100,
  maintainPosition: false,
  hideFocus: true
});
*/

/*var mapContent = $('.map-right-container').jScrollPane();
var api = mapContent.data('jsp');

api.reinitialise();*/

 $('.map-right-container').jScrollPane();

mapPropertyCount();
....
```

Comment: Hmm the solution above causes jScrollPane to vanish completely (even after the first ajax call). Also, separating the containers where the html content is pushed and where jScrollPane is called doesn't seem to do anything either

Comment: @user2989731 in my opinion the best approach is the one mentioned first by using reinitialise. It is strange it does not work, be careful the separate container should only be called to set the HTML content, jScrollPane should be initially created and later reinitialises on the map-right-container element.

Comment: Figured it out! It did have to do with updating the html in the element that contained the jscrollpane. Thank you!